# Which framework should I use? [Visual Studio - C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, frameworks

What I'm going to do it's not very complicated so I could still use ".NET Framework 4", however I was wandering if I should use ".NET Framework 6".

".NET Framework 4" it's a good choice because it's compatible even with Windows XP, but perhaps ".NET Framework 6" can make everything faster?

My program is going to open and edit a lot of files (some times bigger than 1GB).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I'm going to use C#.

I'm a noob, so I'm not sure how should a decide which framework it's better.

Comment: This question may be fairly subjective.
Personally I always target .Net 4.5 in my personal projects so I can easily open them up in MonoDevelop and run them on Linux and Mac as well.

Comment: They're only up to 4.6.2, aren't they? Anyway, 4.6.2 will make you coffee and perform other services that, uh, it's a family website and all that, but you get my drift. If that angle's already taken care of, and XP support is required, stick with 4.0.

Comment: Since you are a noob, and not a time traveler, I would use .NET 4.6.  Or if its really simple (console app), and you want to experience the latest and greatest, go with .NET Core

Comment: Do you need to be compatible with older versions of windows/ with Mono? If not go with latest version.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.x is not compatible with Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It will be most beneficial to you to use .Net 4.5 as a new programmer.**

.Net 4.5 forms the general 'core' of what comes in the .Net 5 and .Net 6 versions.  .net 4.5 is also fairly common in business applications used today.  If you find you need some of the newer features of the language (the Documentation section has a pretty solid rundown of these features) you should upgrade to that version.

In addition, 4.5 is the most 'well understood' version and will make getting questions answered much easier.

Comment: I guess I'm gonna use .Net 4.5.2.

Comment: Maybe I will use MonoDevelop, so it seems to be the best choice, right?